# Sanity check on factorization of $\langle 5 \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, prime-factorization, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Looking at $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, consisting of $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$ with addition and multiplication adjusted so the ring is closed under both operations.

Clearly $5 = 3 \times 5 = 5 \times 5 = 5 \times 7 = 5 \times 5 \times 5 = \ldots$. It's a little weird that $5$ is its own square and cube, but so it is.

As I was taught here a few weeks ago, this domain is Noetherian, which means that ideals can be factorized finitely and uniquely.

Then $\langle 5 \rangle$ is not a prime ideal but can be factorized as a product of prime ideals. One factor might be $\langle 3, 5, 7 \rangle$, but since $3 = -7$, then $\langle 3, 5 \rangle$ will do. And then $\langle 3, 5 \rangle \langle 3, 5 \rangle = \langle 9, 5 \rangle$, but $9 = -1$, which therefore means $\langle 5 \rangle = \langle 3, 5 \rangle^2$.

Is this right? Or did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: I don't see why nobody said "$\Bbb{Z}_{10}$ is not a domain" yet. Moreover, $\langle 5 \rangle$ is a prime ideal of $\Bbb{Z}_{10}$.

Comment: The given answers and the above comment settled the question completely: the ideal generated by $5$ is prime, so a decomposition $5=ab$ leads to $a=5$ or $b=5$, and then you can find all decompositions. That's all.

Answer (score 5):

Notherian isn't enough for unique factorization of ideals, you need a Dedekind domain for that, which $\Bbb Z_{10}$ is not. In this case, for example, $(5)$ is a prime ideal because $\Bbb Z_{10}/(5)\cong\Bbb Z_5$, and in fact you can get this from the basic ring isomorphism theorems:

> $$\Bbb Z/5\cong \Bbb Z/10 \bigg/ (5\Bbb Z/10)$$

Since $(5)\supseteq (10)$ is a prime ideal of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Wow! This domains are even screwier than I realized.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks yes, very much. you need a lot of things to guarantee unique factorization into ideals. Notherian just means that you have finite inclusions as far as **generation** is concerned, not factorization.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for one thing, you forgot that domains like $\textbf{Z}_{10}$ have numbers that are prime but not reducible. With the calculations you have already done, you can verify that whenever $ab = 5$, either $a = 5$ or $b = 5$. That means prime. Plus you have also observed what happens with $a = b = 5$.

Prime numbers generate prime ideals. And prime ideals are maximal ideals. When you deleted $7$ from $\langle 3, 5, 7 \rangle$, you realized you were removing a redundant generator. But you overlooked that $\langle 3 \rangle$ is the entire ring, and so $\langle 3, 5 \rangle$ is a principal ideal after all, and trivially so.

Of course this does not mean that you're insane, merely that rings such as these are kind of insane by the standards of $\textbf{Z}$ and quadratic integer rings.

Comment: I don't think $\mathbb Z_{10}$ is a domain.

Comment: I don't think "prime ideals are maximal ideals".

Answer (score 1):

A [Noetherian ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_ring) is one with no infinite ascending chain of ideals.  In $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ there is only two possibilities;

- $(0) \subseteq (2)=2\mathbb{Z}_{10}  \subseteq (1)=\mathbb{Z}_{10} $
- $(0) \subseteq (5)=5\mathbb{Z}_{10}  \subseteq (1)=\mathbb{Z}_{10} $

In an Noetherian wring, every element can be factored into irreducibles but not necessarily unique. There's not enough room for things to get complicated.

- $\mathbb{Z}_{10}/5\mathbb{Z}_{10}= \mathbb{Z}_5$ which is a field, so that $(5)$ is prime.

Many interesting rings arise in commutative algebra where these definitions can be important

- $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -1)$
- the span $\langle x^a y^b : b > \sqrt{2} a > 0\rangle $ is not finitely generated.